# How can I highlight specific pieces of text within a blog post?

Tags: text, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I have searched for a simple method to allow a user to highlight a specific piece of text with a user chosen color but have not found one readily apparent. I have found a few methods related to syntax / code highlighting. I am not trying to highlight code but merely text within a blog post. Preferably I would like a simple method that provides a UI button within the editor itself as some users that post articles are not technically savvy and may have issues with short codes. I am currently running Wordpress version 3.5.1.

Comment: Modified question to reflect simple method (which is what I actually need)

Comment: Ok. On topic now but how do you want this to work? You want people to be able to select text and choose it for highlighting in much the way you can choose text and bold it or italicize it?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the numerous WordPress shortcodes plugins? Most have a TinyMCE editor interface.

Comment: Agreed with @helgatheviking Also, I think, but can't remember for sure, that CKEdit will highlight text in a way that might work for you.

Comment: CKEdit work well enough to satisfy my requirements. If @s_ha_dum can post as an answer will approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I rarely recommend plugins, the [CKEditor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/) will do highlighting of selected text. That sounds like exactly what you want. And it is a greatly enhanced editor relative to the default one. Short of creating your own editor buttons and supporting functions, that would be a pretty good choice.